# How do I move a macOS installer from root Applications folder on Monterey

Tags: finder, monterey, data-transfer

On Monterey (macOS 12.4 in a VM), I downloaded a macOS installer by running

`softwareupdate --fetch-full-installer --full-installer-version 10.15.7`

I cannot seem to be allowed to move it from root Applications folder to a exFAT external device, due to what I think might be a permissions related problem.

macOS shows this message

[image: screenshot 1]

I heard of some security features introduced over the past OS iterations, but I'm not aware of the context specifically (so this might have started in releases prior to Monterey).

I didn't disable SIP for this test.

In the root Applications folder the installer shows a smaller size, and it won't launch anymore.

[image: screenshot 2]

If I delete it, then I cannot empty the Trash, macOS shows

[image: screenshot 3]

This happens even after a reboot.

On the shell I see

```bash
test@tests-Mac ~ % sudo rm -rf /Users/test/.Trash/Install\ macOS\ Catalina.app  
Password:  
rm: /Users/test/.Trash/Install macOS Catalina.app/Contents/SharedSupport/InstallESD.dmg: Operation not permitted  
rm: /Users/test/.Trash/Install macOS Catalina.app/Contents/SharedSupport: Directory not empty  
rm: /Users/test/.Trash/Install macOS Catalina.app/Contents: Directory not empty  
rm: /Users/test/.Trash/Install macOS Catalina.app: Directory not empty
```

Curiously enough, this **doesn't happen** with the 12.5 installer.

Comment: Where did you download the installer from, where do you copy to (it to an external drive, what type of filesystem does it have), can you share a screenshot of the error message?

Comment: You most likely can‘t store the Installer on an ExFat filesystem.